# My Selenium WebDriver tests hang on Opera browser

Tags: selenium, opera, freeze

I'm using Opera driver from [this](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver)

and the last version of Opera **browser(37.0.2178.54)**

My test case hangs each time during loading page just after authorization.

I.e. browser became not responding and page is not loaded completely.

The same test case works good on both **Chrome and Firefox**.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is too simple.
You just need to give path of your browser and operadriver like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options

s = Options()
s.binary_location = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe'
driver = webdriver.Opera( executable_path=r'F:\ffmpeg\bin\operadriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
```

Answer (score -1):

With Opera open, do:

```
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + OPERA_PROFILE)
Browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```